# tkinter python 3.4 set zero if DoubleVar or IntVar is empty

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to set a text-box or EntryBox to 0 if this entry box is empty
I can do it if the entrybox's textvariable is a String, but I cant if is a DoubleVar or an IntVar

here is my code

```
mGui = Tk()
mGui.title("GUI")
mGui.geometry('1250x650+10+10')

def mCheck():
  if len(name1.get()) == 0:
    name1.set('noidea')
    mGui.update()
  if (len(name2.get()) == 0):
    name2.set('nofkidea')
    mGui.update()
  if (value1.get()== Empty or (len(str(value2.get()))=0) or (len(str(float(value2.get()))) == 0)):
    name2.set(10)
    mGui.update()
  if (value2.get()== None or (len(str(value2.get()))=0) or (len(str(float(value2.get()))) == 0)):
    name2.set(99999)
    mGui.update()

value1 = DoubleVar()
value2 = DoubleVar()
name1 = StringVar()
name2 = StringVar()
mButtonLoad = Button(mGui, text = "check", command = mCheck, fg = 'Red').place(x=550,y=140)
tText1 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = name1).place(x=10,y=80)
tText2 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = name2).place(x=10,y=100)
vText1 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = value1).place(x=200,y=80)
vText2 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = value2).place(x=200,y=100)

mGui.after(1, mGui.update)
mGui.mainloop()
```

I am getting this error when I Try to set the DoubleVar textboxes to 0 if these ones are empty

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Maybe this is a problem: this `(len(str(value2.get()))=0)` should be `(len(str(value2.get()))==0)`. Also what is `Empty`? Is it some variable or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, I fixed your code, so it works as it supposed if I understand you correctly. The main part was to change your `if` statement to `try` and `except` statement. the reason is that `DoubleVar` will through `ValueError` exception if it cant get the double value. For example, when the Entry is empty or is a string.  Also your `mButtonLoad` is always None, so I fixed that as well. Finally, you dont need to check length of a string to know if its empty. Its enough to use `not` to check it.

```
from tkinter import *


mGui = Tk()
mGui.title("GUI")
mGui.geometry('1250x650+10+10')

def mCheck():

  if not name1.get():
    name1.set('noidea')
    mGui.update()

  if not name2.get():
    name2.set('nofkidea')
    mGui.update()


  try:
      print(value1.get())
  except ValueError as ve:
      name1.set(10)
      mGui.update()
      print(ve)

  try:
      print(value2.get())
  except ValueError as ve:
      name2.set(9999)
      mGui.update()
      print(ve)      


value1 = DoubleVar()
value2 = DoubleVar()

name1 = StringVar()
name2 = StringVar()

mButtonLoad = Button(mGui, text = "check", command = mCheck, fg = 'Red')
mButtonLoad.place(x=550,y=140)

tText1 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = name1).place(x=10,y=80)
tText2 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = name2).place(x=10,y=100)
vText1 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = value1).place(x=200,y=80)
vText2 = Entry(mGui, textvariable = value2).place(x=200,y=100)

mGui.after(1, mGui.update)
mGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: perfect, thanks men, I was struggling with this for a long time, I am new with python